# C# Issues with calling list to method properly

Tags: c#, list, methods, calculator

I am new to lists/arrays and have come across a road block on a project I am working on. I am working on a calculator with two separate methods, one is for adding what the user inputs into the calculator, the other method is to calculate the input from the add method. I'm having issues retrieving the list with the data input from add method and using it for the calculate method to calculate average/min/max. The calculator has an add button and a calculate button. How can I properly call the list from the add method with the data entered to the calculate method?

public partial class frmRealEstateCollections : Form
{
    public frmRealEstateCollections()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // declare variables
    decimal decPropertyValue = 0m;
    List<decimal> decValue = new List<decimal>(10);

    // Data Validation
    try
    {
        decPropertyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPropertyValue.Text);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Numeric value",
            "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        txtPropertyValue.Focus();
    }

    // call list

    decValue = Valuelist(decValue, decPropertyValue);

    foreach (decimal decDisplay in Valuelist(decValue, decPropertyValue))
    {
        lstEnteredValues.Items.Add(decDisplay.ToString("C2"));
    }
}

public List<decimal> Valuelist(List<decimal> decValue, decimal decPropertyValue)
{
    // Create list elements unknown?
    decValue = new List<decimal>(10);

    // Add Value Entered by user to list
    decValue.Add(decPropertyValue);

    // return list
    return decValue;
}

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declared List/Variables to call list Method
    List<decimal> decValue = new List<decimal>(10);
    decimal decPropertyValue = 0m;
    decimal decAverage = 0m;

    // Call List
    decValue = Valuelist(decValue, decPropertyValue);
    decAverage = decValue.Average();

    foreach (decimal decDisplay in Valuelist(decValue, decPropertyValue))
    {
        lstAnalysis.Items.Add(decAverage
            }

}
```

}

Comment: `im having issues retrieving the list from the first combo box` is not a good enough description of your issue...

Comment: Please elaborate your issue.

Comment: I edited post, please reach out if it needs more clarification.

Comment: As @alexw mention you create new instance of list in ValueList method and in button click event. Make this list global for class and then call only add method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-creating the list and therefore overwriting any previous values. You should keep a reference to the list and just operate on that single instance.

```
public partial class frmRealEstateCollections : Form
{
    private List<decimal> _decimalValues = new List<decimal>();

    public frmRealEstateCollections()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // declare variables
        decimal decPropertyValue = 0m;

        // Data Validation
        try
        {
            decPropertyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPropertyValue.Text);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input Numeric value",
                "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            txtPropertyValue.Focus();
        }

        // call list
        _decimalValues.Add(decPropertyValue);       

        lstEnteredValues.Items.Add(decPropertyValue.ToString("C2"));          
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declared List/Variables to call list Method
        decimal decAverage = 0m;

        // Call List
        decAverage = _decimalValues.Average();

        lstAnalysis.Items.Add(decAverage);
    }
}
```

I recommend you read about [object instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)) to get a better understanding of object-oriented code.

Comment: This helped a great deal, i was able to complete my assignment and call the list properly. Thank you!!